# Flutter cannot initialize Stripe plugin because I am using Java custom code

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, stripe-payments

I am trying to initialize the Stripe plugin but I get the following error.
I am using the MainActivity.java but Stripe extends `class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() { }` in the MainActivity.kt.

```
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244): kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property stripeSdk has not been initialized
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at com.flutter.stripe.StripeAndroidPlugin.getStripeSdk(StripeAndroidPlugin.kt:34)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at com.flutter.stripe.StripeAndroidPlugin$onAttachedToEngine$1.invoke(StripeAndroidPlugin.kt:57)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at com.flutter.stripe.StripeAndroidPlugin$onAttachedToEngine$1.invoke(StripeAndroidPlugin.kt:57)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext.getNativeModule(ThemedReactContext.kt:17)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at com.reactnativestripesdk.StripeSdkCardViewManager.createViewInstance(StripeSdkCardViewManager.kt:57)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at com.flutter.stripe.StripeSdkCardPlatformView.<init>(StripeSdkCardPlatformView.kt:33)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at com.flutter.stripe.StripeSdkCardPlatformViewFactory.create(StripeSdkCardPlatformViewFactory.kt:21)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createAndroidViewForPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:151)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:104)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:59)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:178)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$handleMessageFromDart$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:206)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$6ZD1MYkhaLxyPjtoFDxe45u43DI.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(26244):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/flutter (26244): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, lateinit property stripeSdk has not been initialized, null, kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property stripeSdk has not been initialized
```

Comment: https://githubmemory.com/repo/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues/68

Comment: I think there is no answer for me in there.

Comment: You should file an issue with the `flutter_stripe` team to see if/how this is supportable.

Answer (score 0):

go to android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
    
class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I already done that. It doesn't work because I use the Java Main Activity.